# WS02 DSS : URL not found for Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am using Google WS02 DSS(3.5.1) for connecting to a public spreadsheet. Below is the link :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WNuXMi2Kq8dt4psMu6U5UQK9TQ8aD0YoxOYlHavktBk/edit#gid=0

When i am trying to test the newly created datasource, i am getting the below error : 
"URL Notound:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WNuXMi2Kq8dt4psMu6U5UQK9TQ8aD0YoxOYlHavktBk/edit#gid=0"

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the Sharable link of the Google spreadsheet (which ends with 'sharing'). It might solve the issue.